# Firebase Web SDK: refreshing auth token so that email_verified is updated in firestore rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Using Firebase Web SDK, I'm requiring users to verify their email before accessing Firestore documents. I have a Firestore rule that gates the document like this:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
```

I'd like the email verification to be reflected as soon as the user verifies his/her email without requiring the user to sign out and sign back in. Unfortunately `onAuthStateChanged()` doesn't fire when emailVerified changes, so I'm refreshing the client token by polling for changes to `emailVerified`. Something like this:

Note: My examples use the new beta Firebase Web SDK V9 (Modular Web SDK) in case the syntax is unfamiliar.

```
    window.setInterval(() => {
      reload(auth.currentUser).then(() => {
        if (!auth.currentUser?.emailVerified)
          return;

        // unsubscribe the previous onAuthStateChanged() listener
        unsubscribe();

        // resubscribe to auth changes
        unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

          // Yay! user.emailVerified is now true
          console.log(user.emailVerified);

        });

      });
    }, 2000);
```

With the code above, I can get `emailVerified` to be reflected property inside my web app, but the problem arises when I try to make a request to Firestore:

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
  doc(db, 'widgets', 'widget1'),
  snap => {
    console.log(snap);
  },
);
```

That request results in a Firestore permission error. Once the user signs out and signs back in, the Firestore request is accepted.

How can I get the auth token that gets sent to Firestore to be updated with the latest `email_verified` without the user to sign out and and sign back in?

Comment: Is there any chance you can try this on SDK 8.5 or earlier? I hate to ask this, but I'm wondering if there's a race condition in the modular SDKs (and I think 8.6 may also depend on those code paths).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just tested it with SDK 8.6.1 because I had another project using it and it was convenient to test, and it's the same behaviour (just as you expected). I'll try with an older version now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tested it with `firebase@8.3.1` and experienced the same problem. I'm testing against the Firebase emulator, but I think it's a reasonable test because I encountered the same problem with both the emulator and real Firestore when I was testing with `Web SDK V9`.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that this happens on "all" SDK versions Johnny. 1) Just to be certain: you are attaching the `onSnapshot` listener *after* you verified that the user's email is verified, right? 2) Did you consider using `onIdTokenChanged`? That listener *does* fire when the verified state changes, so it'll simplify the code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen (1) Yes, attaching onSnapshot listener after email is verified. I created this sample video for you using dev tools' console. I'm using `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`, but the problem with Firestore security rules is the same: https://recordit.co/UdMfnIhW9K . I'm also using the emulator instead of the real Firestore, but I found the results to be consistent. In the video you see that I have to sign out and sign back in before the `get()` query is successful. I'm using Web SDK 8.6.1. (2) I didn't know about `onIdTokenChanged`. I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: It's a little confusing, but I think I solved the mystery. I first need to `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` and then `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)`. I also need to unsubscribe and re-subscribe to `onAuthStateChanged` after `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()`. `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` has to happen after `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()`, and those combo trigger `onIdTokenChanged` and also updates the token sent to Firestore. Phew!

Comment: Great to hear you found it @Johnny. .    I agree that this looks way more complex than it should be, but if it works... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a series of steps need to happen to refresh the token. After email verification, you need to reload the user AND explicitly get a new id token with `getIdToken(user, true)` after you reload the user. Only after those 2 steps will an updated token be sent to Firestore for queries. You also need to unsubscribe and re-subscribe to `onAuthStateChanged` manually, as that doesn't get triggered on token change. The modified version of my example is:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
  reload(auth.currentUser).then(() => {
    if (!auth.currentUser?.emailVerified)
      return;

    getIdToken(auth.currentUser, true).then(() => {

      // now the new token will be sent to Firestore, yay!

      // unsubscribe the previous onAuthStateChanged() listener
      unsubscribe();

      // resubscribe to auth changes
      unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

        // Yay! user.emailVerified is now true
        console.log(user.emailVerified);

      });

    })
  });
}, 2000);
```

Please post your answer if there's an easier way. I especially don't like the polling part.